# dbus server always calls on name lost callback. its not getting session with daemon

Tags: dbus

Having doubt regarding DBus. I installed d-bus in my linux pc and working with terminal. then i did dbus-launch for running the dbus daemon in session mode. I have written the dbus server code with help of gio, glib dbus libraries.

Dbus server code will try to call g_dbus_own_name api with session type and unique well known name and it will have two callbacks( on name acquired and on name lost). But it is always calling on name lost callback.

I don't what i am missing. Please anybody knows about steps to create dbus server. I am sure that my code is correct. That is just simple server will call g_dbus_own_name api.

## ./myserver  if i run like that.. its not able to connect with daemon i guess..

I am not sure..

Please help me.